# How do I align several lines of text in different table columns in a Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to properly align several lines of text in 2 different Word table columns. To better understand the issue, look at the attached picture where the word "break" is misaligned with "20 min" (all in red. I am not looking for solutions that involve adding extra rows to have one paragraph per row. Thank you for your help!

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I don't think there is any automated way other than using more rows. You can add hard line feeds (Shift-Enter) in the right hand column to match the number of lines in each paragraph in the middle column, but that will break down if you change the middle column width or use anything in the middle column that modifies spacing (e.g. if you increase the point size of some of your text or insert a superscript). (You can match some of those things by putting the same formatted characters in the right hand column and coloring them white, but I really wouldn't want to have to maintain that!)

Comment: It definitely looks like there's a line spacing difference between "break" and the corresponding "20 min" - so I would investigate that first. Alternatively, you could try putting each of the lines on separate rows (rather than using returns to add the desired separation), then just removing the border between the rows to achieve the same look as your screenshot above; it may help keep things lined up a little better.

Comment: Using the Soft Return (Shift + Enter) in the 2nd column did the trick and helped me align everything perfectly! No need for anything else. Thank you so much everybody for the help!